# Spring OAuth2/OIDC - OAuth2AuthorizedClientService is not registering the User Principal (authroizedClient)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

I am implementing OIDC in my non-spring boot application. Below is my configuration for my OIDC client and I am trying to get the OAuth2AuthorizedClient from the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService, I am getting null. Basically the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService is not registering the client principal (authorizedClient).
I was getting redirect to okta (auth Server) login page and getting redirected to my controller method after authentication with okta (auth Server)…

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class ClientSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index/4_0/**")
        .authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/okta_login")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/okta_login")
        .clientRegistrationRepository(oktaRegistrationRepository())
        .authorizedClientService(authorizedClientService());
}

@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {
    return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(oktaRegistrationRepository());
}

@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository oktaRegistrationRepository() {
    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.oktaClientRegistration());
}
private ClientRegistration oktaClientRegistration() {
    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("okta").clientId("client id *********")
            .clientSecret("client secret ********")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUriTemplate("http://localhost:9088/myApp/login/oauth2/code/okta")
            .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
            .authorizationUri("https://myorg.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize")
            .tokenUri("https://myorg.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token")
            .userInfoUri("https://myorg.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo")
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .jwkSetUri("https://myorg.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys").clientName("Okta")
            .build();
        }   
 }
```

initializer:

```
public class ClientSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
        public ClientSecurityInitializer() {
            super(ClientSecurityConfigurer.class);
        }
}
```

custom login page:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value="/okta_login")
public String oktaLogin(){
    return "redirect:/oauth2/authorization/okta";
    }
}
```

my app controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index/4_0")
public class ClientController_4_0 {

@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/client", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String getIndex(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.getAuthorizedClient(authentication);
    OAuth2AccessToken token = (OAuth2AccessToken) authorizedClient.getAccessToken();
    String tokenValue = token.getValue();
    return "v4_0/client";
}

private OAuth2AuthorizedClient getAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
    return this.authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
        authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());
}
}
```

getting null on calling

```
 OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.getAuthorizedClient(authentication);
```

I autowired the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService , where the auhtorizedClients were null, but the clientRegistrationRepository is getting loaded, as I loaded it from configuration… guess after authenticated, the client principal is not getting loaded as authorizedClients…

not sure of where I am doing wrong…any suggestion would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out… the issue is related to my SecurityInitializer class. As my app is already a Spring app (not spring boot), I don’t need to load my SecurityConfig class in it. So my Security Initializer class will be as below…

```
public class ClientSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. But I'm using spring boot. Any ideas?

Comment: Clearing browser cookies fixed the problem